# Prove that lim ${a_n}$ = 0 implies lim $\sqrt {a_n}$ = 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do you prove that given a non-negative sequence ${a_n}$, lim ${a_n}$ = 0 implies lim $\sqrt {a_n}$ = 0?

By definition of limit in analysis I can assume that given $ϵ>0$, I have $a_n-0<ϵ$, which is just $a_n<ϵ$, for n>>1.

If I can claim that $\sqrt {a_n} < {a_n} < ϵ$ for all $a_n$ I may be able to finish the proof, but that is not true for $0\lt a_n\lt1$.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Fix any  $\varepsilon >0$.

- Since $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, you now that, taking $\varepsilon^\prime=\varepsilon^2 > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $0 \leq a_n \leq \varepsilon^\prime$ for all $n \geq N$.
- Since the function $s\colon x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, we know that if $0\leq x \leq {\varepsilon}^\prime$ then $s(0) \leq s(x) \leq s({\varepsilon}^\prime)$.

Can you conclude?

Comment: Why don't we just say square root is continuous on its domain and so we can pass limit inside square root? Sounds like your answer just reinvents the wheel

Comment: Because that result on continuous functions may not be known to the OP, who mentions $\varepsilon$ (and thus seems to be learning limits, using for now the $\varepsilon,\delta$ definition). One can only use theorems if theorems are known.

Comment: Clement C., in calculus courses, is it not proved that you can pass limits under continuous for sequences as with functions? i already forgot the precise order of my calculus classes

Answer (score 0):

That's it? This is the same thing as with functions. Square root is continuous on its domain and so we can pass limit inside square root:

$\lim \sqrt {a_n} = \sqrt {\lim a_n} = \sqrt {0} = 0$